Fixed-effects using demeaned data: Why are the demeaned predictions different from original data w/ fixed effects?
I'm hoping someone can help me understand why a fit regression model making predictions on  panel data with group fixed-effects, outputs different results than the same model predicting on the same data but demeaned.
For example, let's say I have some regression looking at the effect of climate conditions temperature and precipitation on GDP, with data grouped by country and year (i = country, t = year, Y is year fixed effects and a is country fixed effects):
GDPit = B1 * tempit + B2 * precipit + Yt + ai + eit
I demean the dependent variable and all co-variates for both country and year, such that for any variable xit:
x_dmit = xit - x̄i - x̄t
I can then run this regression on the demeaned data (with intercept = 0):
GDP_dmit = B_dm1 * temp_dmit + B_dm2 * precip_dmit
The coefficients between these two regressions are equal, because we have essentially baked the fixed effect into the data.
B_dm1 == B1, B_dm2 == B2
However, if I take a row of in-sample data from the original dataset and the corresponding row of demeaned data and use the covariate data to predict the dependent variable for each row, the prediction from the demeaned data is different than the prediction from the original data with fixed effects included.
I don't feel like I have a good intuition for why the predictions are different. It is not simply because the fixed-effects are "missing" from the prediction - if it were, then adding them to the prediction would work. Since the model coefficients are the same, it implicates some difference between the datasets that I am not fully grasping, but I would like to be able to understand why this is the case.
